# Is XXVCA3 and XXVCS1 the same product?

Tags: buck-rogers, tsr, product-identification

TSR's [Buck Rogers XXVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_Rogers_XXVC) game had a good number of supplements and modules. When trying to get a simple list of products and matching them to images of the covers I came across something interesting. From what I can see the Adventure called *Deimos Mandate* has both XXVCA3 AND XXVCS1 product codes. Is that correct? Any idea why it panned out that way if it is?

The two images below are from the module. The first image is from the produced book that was on the shelves. The 2nd image is from a 1991 product catalog and has the different number. If the firs image is what was final, then that means there never was a XXVCS1, or at least XXVCA3 is the same thing. The 'S' line started with XXVCS2.

[image]
[image: Cover as shown in the 1991 TSR Product Catalog. Published product used a different cover design]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same product. The product series was coded 25CS. TSR printed comps in the 1991 catalog for the hobby channel.

XXVCA1 and XXVCA2 were *Buck Rogers in the 25 Century* and *NEO in the 25th Century*, respectively, both adventure modules for the game.